# How to calculate confidence intervals of non linear sigmoidal fitting curve?

Tags: confidence-interval, least-squares, standard-error, nonlinear

I'm not using R or any other stats framework, I'm trying to implement myself an algorithm to optimize the fitting curve and to calculate the EC50 confidence intervals.
Problem I have is my lack of knowledge in this field, so almost everything I find is to do it using R and for the rest appears to be different approaches so I don't know if its the correct one.
I think I did pretty well fitting the curve using the Gauss-Newton method, I plotted the curve and its looking good.
Trying to calculate EC confidence intervals using this formula:

```
SE = sqrt(SUM((Y-Y')^2)/(N-2))
```

Where N is my number of scores, Y actual score of sample data, and Y' the prediction.

About confidence interval formula:

```
CI = Y +- crit.tvalue * SE * sqrt( (1/N-2) + ((EC50-xm)^2/SSx) )
```

Where SE is the formula above for standard error, n-2 are deegress of freedom, EC50 is the approximated EC50 value for what I'm calculating the confidence interval, "xm" is the mean of all x values and SSx is:

```
SSx= SUM((Xi-Xm)^2)
```

Is it correct? If not, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantity

$$ E \propto \sum_{i}(y-\hat{y})^2$$

is actually an estimate of the variability left in the data once you're removed the structural part. In other words, $E$ is proportional to the noise in the data and not a good way to get confidence intervals for your fit.  Confidence intervals don't deal with variability in the data, they deal with *variability in the estimated parameters*.  That's different.

I'm assuming that you're using least squares, and so that means you are using a Gaussian likelihood (not important to you, just setting up some theory).  Getting confidence intervals for a non-linear fit is kind of tricky because you have to:

- Estimate the hessian of your loss
- Use the delta method to get estimates of the variance of the non-linear curve.

Are you using software at all for this?

Comment: Yes, Im using software, but my own software. And yes, im using least squares. Its hard to me to undestand that E its not a good way to estimate confidence intervals but its a valid way? How its this? My curve its always a sigmoidal curve, what maybe it simplifies a bit the problem. Thanks

Comment: This is the video from where i got the formulas:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8ldtlm8BbA